# Back button isn't working with a hierarchal route

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-routing

I am using AngularDart and I am trying to set up a route so that I can get notified when the user clicks back from `/user/1` to `/user`.

I am only getting the print message out when I go from `/user -> /user/1` but nothing when `/user/1 -> /user`. I would have expected to get the "Show list of users" messages but the enter event doesn't fire

```dart
class RouterExample {

  void call(Router router, ViewFactory views) {
    views.configure({
        'users': ngRoute(
            path: '/user',
            enter: (_) {
              print('Show list of users');
            },
            leave: (_) {
              print('Hide list of users');
            },
            mount: {
                'view' : ngRoute(
                    path: '/:id',
                    enter: (_) {
                      print('Show a user');
                    },
                    leave: (_) {
                      print('Hide user');
                    }
                )
            }
        )
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically your `users` route is still *active* when you go from `/user/1` to `/user`.

To handle list as you want you should define another mount entry :

```dart
class RouterExample {
  void call(Router router, ViewFactory views) {
    views.configure({
      'users': ngRoute(
        path: '/user',
        mount: {
          'view' : ngRoute(
            path: '/:id',
            enter: (_) => print('Show a user'),
            leave: (_) => print('Hide user')
          ),
          'list': ngRoute(
            path: '',
            enter: (_) => print('Show list of users'),
            leave: (_) => print('Hide list of users')
          )
        }
      )
    });
  }
}
```